# how to connect a C# project with Access database placed on server (NOT local network) to edit and view?

Tags: c#, ms-access, server

I have some Databases built in Access and I want to be able to view and edit them when I'm not connected to a local server\network.

How can I access with C# to view and edit the Access databases placed on a server without VPN or SMB (which means creating local network). Is it possible to edit it realtime on the server?

This needs to be accessed by more than one people, thus I also want for example block a table if one's already editing it (so here also goes the FTP protocol - to download and edit on the PC and reupload)

I hope I was clear enough and provided enough info, thanks for all helpers!! Enlighten me please :)

Comment: You design is bad.  Access is not meant for multiuser environment.  You could put file on shared drive so it can be accessed by folder.filename (and make property shared), but the often the file will get locked.  If you only want one user access then build a service so only one person can download file at one time.

Comment: I use Access just as the database and the C# to build the interface. Is there any other way to do it?
For example (idk if that's possible): Can I make an SQL server with my current built in Access and to edit that with C#?
And about the FTP protocol, do you think it is a fair solution?

Comment: The ideal solution is to use a database like SQL Server which is designed to handle multi-users which contains locks to prevent more than one user changing an object simultaneously.   Using BulkCopy you can move the data from Access to SQL Server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would first have to ask how end users going to run and use the C# program?

Desktop: users would need a network connection to the server. (most likly a VPN).

Web based: users would need a network connection to the WEB SERVER. This could also be a VPN, or could be a web server that is public facing. this would then require logons for security.

If users don't have a network connection, then it not going to matter if this is oracle, MySQL, SQL server or Access. And in fact, if this is web based, then users need to be able to connect to that web server.

So, without some kind of network connection to that server or computer where the data resides, and you eliminated a VPN, then your options are limited.

You can build a web site and place it on a server. However, if users don't have any kind of network connection even in the case of a web site, then I fail to see how you can even suggest using FTP let alone any other kind of connection.

> This needs to be accessed by more than one people,

Ok, you need multi-user. However the locking up a whole table on sql server to allow only one user is actually quite difficult.

But, we can leave that you want one user in a given table at one time. (but both Access and a web site would in fact allow multiple users - even editing the same table).

All in all?
Then this suggests the most obvious solution: run a web server, and that would allow any user to connect to the web site, and the web site then can read/talk/use the access database that resides on that server. And this then again means that you don't need any client software installed.

FTP is not a practial solution - since it only works on a whole file.

So, users will require some means to connect to some server. That being the case, then write your C# appliation as web based, and thus no client software will be required, and the only software that interacts with the access file on that server will be the web site.

So, running a web site on that server does seem to be the best option.
So, we heading towards a web solution.

So then software would stay and run 100% on the server side, and thus zero client software would be required other then that of a browser.

Comment: I didn't state if the C# program will be web-based or on the desktop 'cause I didn't know which option is better, so I decided to leave this part to you - the professionalists.
About the VPN, the problem is that I don't want the users to get troubled with all these settings (unless there is some option to apply it only on the software though the C# code that I don't know about). And all of the users definitely have internet connection.

Thanks for your willing to help though! You really put a lot of effort in that, I appreciate that!

Comment: Ok then - that really suggests that a web based app would be the best approach. Access is not the best for that type of system, but if the user count only say hits about 5-15 users, then it can work rather fine. And since you are now clear that you were asking for advice? I'll edit my post to remove any condescending tone.

Comment: See my update and edits - I do rather suggest the web road based on your feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your magnificent advice! You helped me a lot, appreciate!

Comment: I have another question that came to my mind now. I built the whole database and the whole interface on Access, now I need to make it work online. Is there anyway to build something that interacts with both of them so I won't need to build the whole interface again in C# and maybe save some effort. (I hope I was clear enough, thanks!)

Comment: If you wrote the software in vb.net (desktop), or FoxPro, or Access or in fact ANY other desktop development tool? They don't work on the web - it not really different then having written a desktop program in FoxPro, and then by some act of magic it will now all of a sudden run on a Mac computer, or even a Android phone for that matter.  The best option is to use a cloud hosted server and use remote desktop. Other option is using SQL azure for the database back end, and continue to use and deploy the access application on each desktop Any computer with internet will thus work from any location

Answer (score 0):

I developed a simple Python web server to work with the Access DB via HTTP:

https://github.com/vikilpet/MS-Access-HTTP-Server

Probably this is not an ideal solution for your case but it may be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! That seems some kind of a solution, I just want to keep it simple thus I don't want to involve also python and other languages than C# and SQL (Access).